# Adding additional nodes to network in Grass GIS

Tags: grass-gis, network

I have created a network in Grass GIS (using v.net, nodes option). I then want to "disrupt" the network (i.e., create some road blockages) and add in nodes to the new line ends where road blockages have occurred.

However, I want to keep the category values from the original network the same (so I can compare the network before and after disruption). I've tried a couple of ways of doing this but with no success so far.

For example, copying the nodes from the original network (using v.extract) and then using v.net, connect option to add in these nodes to my disrupted network.

Does anyone know how to add in new nodes to an existing grass network? I'd prefer to not have to do this manually, as there are thousands of blockages.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [v.edit](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.edit.html) which offers automated editing of vector maps (you can selectively modify an existing vector map which will be interesting in your case).